# How to move a Powerpack Ovalshape in VS using threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to make a model that acts like sub-atomic particles for an interesting project. I understand that C# isn't exactly the best coding language for this kind of undertaking, however since I'm pretty newish to coding and only now C# and Java I decided I would just try on C#.

Currently what I'm trying to do is get the ovalShape, representing a particle, to passively move towards oppositely charged particles. To get this to run in the background all the time I decided to use threads, but when I ran my simple test for proof of concept of moving the ovalshape with a thread, it didnt move at all and I don't understand why.

I set up the thread normally using

```
Thread thrFOA = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ForceOfAttraction));
```

and then made my test background function:

```
        public  void ForceOfAttraction()
    {
        ovalShape1.SetBounds(ovalShape1.Location.X + 1, ovalShape1.Location.Y, ovalShape1.Width, ovalShape1.Height);
        ovalShape1.Refresh();
    }
```

So I thought this should just make it so that the oval slowly moves across the screen, being moved a pixel at a time, however there was no movement at all and I don't understand why not. I also tried `this.Refresh();` instead of `ovalShape1.Refresh();` as it is in the form class, but the same result.

I appreciate the time and help, thanks!

Comment: Have you started the thread? (`thrFOA.Start();`). Also, if you're using winforms or wpf, you can only update the position of the controls from the main thread

Comment: Also, if you wan to "move slowly", you need some kind of loop. Here, you're changing the position only once